# Nested Query Search Performance

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, nested, aggregation

I'm wondering how much of a performance improvement can I expect by adding `"_source": false,` to my `_search` query. I'm doing a `_search` query with `nested` data with a filter aggregation. I understand `_source` is read from disk whereas `aggs` are calculated in memory. So by setting `"_source": false,` should I expected a dramatic improvement in my search response time?